# Visual Studio 20149 Remote debugger windows does not show Application pool and user names

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2019, remote-debugging, windows-server-2019

I had a Windows 2008 Server which was being used as Application server that has recently been upgraded to Windows 2012 -> Windows Server 2016 -> Windows Server 2019.

All of the applications under IIS work, but one. I am trying to figure out what is wrong. I have installed Visual Studio 2019 Remote Debugging tool on the server and trying to attach to the erroneous project under IIS.

I have the Remote Debugger running
[image: Remote debugger window]

but when I try to attach to remote process the Application pool and user names do not show up in the "Attach to process" window.
[image: Attach to process window]

Since I can not see the details I can not connect to my application and debug. I am sure that "Show processes from all users" is checked.

I know that if the application does not run on the server it does not show up in this list, but I have called other applications under the site which are running but they don't appear either.

Answer (score 0):

Try run the remote debugger under the different user account:

- You can stop the remote debugger and restart it with the account you are using on the local computer.
- You can start the remote debugger from the command line with the /allow  parameter: msvsmon /allow username@computer
- You can add the user to the remote debugger's permissions (in the
  remote debugger window, Tools > Permissions).
- If you can't use the methods in the preceding steps, you can allow
  any user to do remote debugging. In the remote debugger window, go to
  the Tools > Options dialog. When you select No Authentication, you
  can then check Allow any user to debug. However, you should use this
  option only if you have no choice, or if you are on a private
  network.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am already running the Remote Debugger with no Authentication and allow any user debug. It is safe to do because I run the servers and run the debugger only when I need.

Comment: Have you tried to run Visual studio as an administrator?